# How to calculate different combinations of elements with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have a set of $n$ different elements, and $m$, $m>n$, locations where I can put any element of that set.

The answer to the question “how many different combinations can I build with $m$ locations, each one taking anyone of the $n$ elements?” is just $n^m$.

However, imagine that now some elements $p_i$ of the original set must appear exactly $i$ times in the resulting combination of length $m$, while others don’t have any restriction on the number of times they appear.

How can I calculate the number of possible different combinations?

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that  the number of the special elements is $k$.

First choose $ki$ positions (from $m$) for the special elements, permute the elements arbitrarily over the positions and then fill the rest positions with all possible combinations of the rest elements ending with the expression
$$
\frac{m!}{(m-ki)!(i!)^k}(n-k)^{m-ki}.
$$